# reading key values from string

Tags: python, json, yaml

I'm getting the following output from my POST API request (yaml) and need to get key,value from it. tried to convert to json but didn't work as expected.

```
x = {'map_key': '- TYPE: UK\nNAME: TOM\n- TYPE: US\nNAME: BOB'}

test = json.dumps(x['map_key'].replace("-",""), indent=4)
```

How can i get TYPE,NAME values from the above x variable

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Need to get key value pairs, test['TYPE'] , test['NAME'], like a dictionary

Comment: It looks like the API result `- TYPE: UK\nNAME: TOM\n- TYPE: US\nNAME: BOB` is trying to be YAML, but it is not actually valid YAML so parsing it with [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) raises an error. Is this data correct? Perhaps you modified the structure inadvertently when asking your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to build a dictionary out of the map_key value. Perhaps something like this:

```
x = {'map_key': '- TYPE: UK\nNAME: TOM\n- TYPE: US\nNAME: BOB'}

result = {}

for token in x['map_key'].split('\n'):
    k, v = token.split(':')
    result.setdefault(k.split()[-1], []).append(v.strip())

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'TYPE': ['UK', 'US'], 'NAME': ['TOM', 'BOB']}
```